# How to align all items between them (images, titles, texts, buttons) in differents div's row with CSS?

Tags: css, flexbox, visual-composer

I know this topic has already get an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363673/centering-buttons-from-different-divs), but there is a little difference in my case.

You have to know that unfortunately I can't edit the HTML because I use Visual Composer for WordPress that generate its own HTML. I can only add classes or IDs on HTML tags via Visual Composer in the WordPress backoffice. It will be so long to edit the HTML of every Visual Composer blocks (with the WordPress text mode). So I have to find another efficient way to do it.

So, to align all the items between them I tried many solutions:

I first tried to use a min-height on the parent div that is set to a relative position, then I put the buttons at absolute position with a bottom of 0.
It worked for the buttons alignment but I want it to be automatic and managed by itself in case when there is more text content and I don't want to change several times the min-height in several responsive modes.

So I tried the FlexBox solution of the [link I shared above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363673/centering-buttons-from-different-divs).
This solution works when we have only an image, a text and a button,
but in my case I have a title between each of the images and text contents, so it means we can have a title on 1 line or 2 lines or more... The problem with that is a misalignment of the titles between themselves and the "Lorem Ipsum" texts as well.

How can I manage it?

Thank you for the help.

I provided the code snippets to see my issue:

```css
.sameblockheight, .wpb_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.vc_column-inner {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.wpb_wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.subrow {
  display: flex;
}

.subrow > div {
  width: 200px;
}

.vc_column-inner {
  padding: 6% 8%;
}

.button-blue {
  text-align: center;
}

.alignnone {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="subrow">

 <div class="sameblockheight grid-col-3">
  <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1530896965169">
   <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p>
     <img class="alignnone" src=http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/47/1b/54/471b54ad-a6cf-f61e-2f33-11ffc6bd8215/icon100x100.jpeg>
    </p>
    <h5 style="text-align: center;">Title on 1 line</h5>
    <p class="p-height" style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur beatae officiis ea, corporis eos quas temporibus asperiores iste impedit laborum et non, itaque eaque dignissimos. Distinctio, quaerat vel consectetur! Pariatur.</p>
    <a class="button-blue" href="#">Learn more</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="sameblockheight grid-col-3">
  <div class="vc_column-inner ">
   <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p>
     <img class="alignnone" src=http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/47/1b/54/471b54ad-a6cf-f61e-2f33-11ffc6bd8215/icon100x100.jpeg>
    </p>
    <h5 style="text-align: center;">Title on 2 lines ...............................</h5>
    <p class="p-height" style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque quas in quod quae magni eligendi dicta totam, placeat eveniet facere cupiditate natus aut, impedit incidunt error veritatis libero suscipit nisi.</p>
    <a class="button-blue" href="#">Learn more</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="sameblockheight grid-col-3">
  <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1530896977260">
   <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p>
     <img class="alignnone" src=http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/47/1b/54/471b54ad-a6cf-f61e-2f33-11ffc6bd8215/icon100x100.jpeg>
    </p>
    <h5 style="text-align: center;">Title on 3 lines ................ ................. ......................... ............... ...........</h5>
    <p class="p-height" style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In ullam optio quia nam aliquam numquam ipsa incidunt possimus consequatur sed animi hic facere mollitia facilis libero cupiditate eaque, molestiae voluptas!</p>
    <a class="button-blue" href="https://staging.unify.com/en/solutions/voice-platforms/preconfigured-unified-communications">Learn more</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="sameblockheight grid-col-3">
  <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1530896983086">
   <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p>
     <img class="alignnone" src=http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/47/1b/54/471b54ad-a6cf-f61e-2f33-11ffc6bd8215/icon100x100.jpeg>
    </p>
    <h5 style="text-align: center;">Title</h5>
    <p class="p-height" style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui provident eum voluptas veritatis ducimus iste enim recusandae aliquid sequi ad sapiente dolore similique nihil eos placeat, consectetur odit beatae voluptatum?</p>
    <a class="button-blue" href="#">Learn more</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: First, in your screenshot the buttons are not 'misaligned'  but the texts are. Second, so we could help you, please provide a working snippet that replicates your problem. Take example from the question you yourself linked in your own question

Comment: Yes, I agree, it is my first question here, sorry for my errors. Now I improved my question and I provided a code snippet. Thank you Mihai T.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution i can think of with only CSS is to add a `min-height` to your titles `h5`. For example i added `min-height:40px` and now, all the `h5` are equal in height. You can set a bigger/smaller one.

The downsize is that if a title is larger that the `min-height` you set you have that problem again.

One fullproof solution would be to add a little javascript/jQuery to make the `h5` equal in height without setting a 'hardcoded' `min-height`.

If you want/can use javaScript/jQuery let me know and i'll make a solution with that. If not, and you want to use only CSS, the below solution is the only one that i can think of.

```css
h5 {
 min-height:40px;
 margin-top:0;
}


.sameblockheight, .wpb_wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.vc_column-inner {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
}

.wpb_wrapper {
  flex-grow: 1;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.subrow {
  display: flex;
}

.subrow > div {
  width: 200px;
}

.vc_column-inner {
  padding: 6% 8%;
}

.button-blue {
  text-align: center;
}

.alignnone {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="subrow">

 <div class="sameblockheight grid-col-3">
  <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1530896965169">
   <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p>
     <img class="alignnone" src=http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/47/1b/54/471b54ad-a6cf-f61e-2f33-11ffc6bd8215/icon100x100.jpeg>
    </p>
    <h5 style="text-align: center;">Title on 1 line</h5>
    <p class="p-height" style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur beatae officiis ea, corporis eos quas temporibus asperiores iste impedit laborum et non, itaque eaque dignissimos. Distinctio, quaerat vel consectetur! Pariatur.</p>
    <a class="button-blue" href="#">Learn more</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="sameblockheight grid-col-3">
  <div class="vc_column-inner ">
   <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p>
     <img class="alignnone" src=http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/47/1b/54/471b54ad-a6cf-f61e-2f33-11ffc6bd8215/icon100x100.jpeg>
    </p>
    <h5 style="text-align: center;">Title on 2 lines ...............................</h5>
    <p class="p-height" style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Neque quas in quod quae magni eligendi dicta totam, placeat eveniet facere cupiditate natus aut, impedit incidunt error veritatis libero suscipit nisi.</p>
    <a class="button-blue" href="#">Learn more</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="sameblockheight grid-col-3">
  <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1530896977260">
   <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p>
     <img class="alignnone" src=http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/47/1b/54/471b54ad-a6cf-f61e-2f33-11ffc6bd8215/icon100x100.jpeg>
    </p>
    <h5 style="text-align: center;">Title on 3 lines ................ ................. ......................... ............... ...........</h5>
    <p class="p-height" style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. In ullam optio quia nam aliquam numquam ipsa incidunt possimus consequatur sed animi hic facere mollitia facilis libero cupiditate eaque, molestiae voluptas!</p>
    <a class="button-blue" href="https://staging.unify.com/en/solutions/voice-platforms/preconfigured-unified-communications">Learn more</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="sameblockheight grid-col-3">
  <div class="vc_column-inner vc_custom_1530896983086">
   <div class="wpb_wrapper">
    <p>
     <img class="alignnone" src=http://a1.mzstatic.com/us/r30/Purple/v4/47/1b/54/471b54ad-a6cf-f61e-2f33-11ffc6bd8215/icon100x100.jpeg>
    </p>
    <h5 style="text-align: center;">Title</h5>
    <p class="p-height" style="text-align: center;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Qui provident eum voluptas veritatis ducimus iste enim recusandae aliquid sequi ad sapiente dolore similique nihil eos placeat, consectetur odit beatae voluptatum?</p>
    <a class="button-blue" href="#">Learn more</a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Mihai T. I can use JavaScript/jQuery in my environment but your first solution with "min-height" on the titles works. But I needed to add a "flex-grow: 1;" to the ".p-height" class. I did many tests and I don't know why it works as I am not an expert in FlexBox, but it is fine like that. I will just have to adjust the min-height in responsive mode.

Comment: @FaroukTbahriti. If this answer helped you, please don't forget to rate/accept my answer. ///// More info: flex-grow specifies how much the element occupies inside a flex container relative to the other elements inside that container. for eg if you have 2 columns in a container and one has `flex-grow:2` and one has `flex-grow:1` . The one with `flex-grow:2` will occupy 2/3 of the container and the other one 1/3 of the container :). Hope this explanation helps you. read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow).

Comment: Ok, it is done. Now I understood why the flex-grow worked for me. Can you rate my question in a better way now I improved it? Thank you.

Comment: @FaroukTbahriti it is possible to give only give you 1 point at the question. Done